# Multiple GPOs with Security Filtering or Single GPO with Item Level Targeting?

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have multiple GPOs for User Experience stuff (Eg: Shortcuts as GPP in User Configuration) which impacts a number of OUs and their users. It's currently one GPO per 'item' (Eg: shortcut, file) with a Security Filter applied to the GPO defining a security group but there is a growing number of them.

It could be said that some files and shortcuts are sensitive in nature (Not just content but paths and names) so what would the security and performance ramifications be if I merged all applicable things into a single GPO and used item-level targeting on user security group instead?

Answer (score 2):

If the files/folders are sensitive then they should be restricted access at a filesystem level on the filserver where the files/folders/whatever is hosted, not by just controlling who has the shortcut and who has not.

That being said - I'e never encountered where item level targeting have failed on group lookups or similar. I still wouldn't trust it to be my single set of policies...

Answer (score 0):

Not only should the permissions be set at the filesystem, but you should consider installing the RMS portion of windows server and protecting the files with rights management.

If the paths and names are sensitive you should also enable access based enumeration on the shares to hide the filenames

Comment: AD RMS is an absolute disaster of a product, though. Azure RMS is far superior (though not free).

Comment: What's wrong with adrms?

Comment: I did a check, I don't see much difference between the 2, why bother with the pay version when the windows version is free and works like a charm.